# How to solve mypy error for @property with pydantic @computed_field?

Tags: python, mypy, pydantic

I need to decorate `@property` with the `@computed_field` from pydantic
(to automatically generate key-value pairs and include them in a FastAPI JSON Response).
In the following example, mypy displays an error.
If there is an error, how can I fix it?
If everything is correct, how do I disable this mypy message?

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, computed_field

class MyClass(BaseModel):

    value1: str
    value2: str

    @computed_field
    @property
    def joined_values(self) -> str:
        return self.value1 + self.value2


obj = MyClass(value1="1", value2="2")
print(f"{obj.joined_values=}")  # obj.joined_values='12'
```

mypy error:

```
$ mypy . 
stackperflow_pydantic_property.py:25: error: Decorators on top of @property are not supported  [misc]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 2 source files)
```

versions:

```
$ python -V
Python 3.10.11

$ pip list
mypy                  1.7.1
pydantic              2.5.2
```

Comment: Make your own wrapper with return type declared as a descriptor. Decorated properties are not supported, but there's nothing wrong with building a property-like descriptor yourself, it's only a few lines of code. You don't have to do it on runtime, implementation will still return `computed_field(property(your_method))`, it will work well if you don't need setter or deleter.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not supported by mypy, see the warning in [the documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/usage/computed_fields/).